# Get virus/threat information from microsoft via threat id

Tags: malware, anti-virus, windows-defender

I don't know if this is the right place for a question like this but:

first, I have a virus report from windows defender with a threat id. For example this is the threat id of the eicar testfile: "2147519003".

When I google just this id, the first hit is [this site from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Virus%3aDOS%2fEICAR_Test_File&threatid=2147519003) that explanes the threat. Thats exactly what I am looking for. But now to my problem.

How can I search for a differend threat id on the microsoft site? When looking in the url, I can see that there should be a malware-encyclopedia "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description". Going to this site takes me to "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats".

On this site are some statistic but also a search. But when I search the eicar threat id "2147519003" I wont get any hits. The site would be perfect because in the url I could just simply change the search query to get my results with a different id but this search wont find anything..

So my final question: is there a way to place a threat id into any microsoft url to get to a a site like the first one I linked?